# React router and useCallback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have the following routes:

```
const makeIndexRoutes = (): React.ReactElement => (
  <Switch>
    <Redirect exact from="/" to="/estimates" />
    <Route exact path="/estimates" component={CostingPage} />
    <Route exact path="/estimates/new" component={NewEstimatePage} />
    <Route exact path="/estimates/edit/:id" component={EditEstimatePage} />
  </Switch>
);
```

And in another file I try to make a redirect on button click like this:

```
  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    // do some action on 'close' button click
    <Redirect to='/estimates'></Redirect>
  }, []);
```

But nothing happens, is anyone able to guide me on what I am potentially doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that this is a useCallback instead of a regular function?

Comment: According to the best practices we should use useCallback.

Comment: That depends :)

Comment: Could you explain more? Some link?

Comment: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback
He explains when not to and when to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work, what you want to is programmatically redirect.

For this, you should do something like this:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
const history = useHistory();
const handleClose = () => {
  history.push('/estimates');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will not work because `Redirect` component should be rendered in JSX in order for it to work and change the route.

You can use one of the following options to change the route

1. Use `history` object from router props

   ```
   props.history.push('/estimates')
   ```

   you could also use [useHistory](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook provided by react router to access the `history` object.
2. Use `Link` component provided by react router. It will automatically change the route without needing a click listener

   ```
   <Link to="/estimates">Estimates</Link>
   ```

For more details see:

- [Link Component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)
- [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)